# How to access R.file If I know files string name?

Tags: java, android, string

I am making a program where it needs to open various songs with `MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.filename);`  but because I have a lot of songs, I need to geenrate file name programically with `String s = "song" + Integer.toString(i);` in my for loop. (File names are song1,song2,song3 etc.)

But the problem is when I try to access file with R.raw.s,it shows "unresolved symbol s"

Any help?

Comment: `int identifier = getResources().getIdentifier(s, "video/mp3", getPackageName()); MediaPlayer.create(this, identifier);`

Comment: thanks a lot,I've just found out how to do it,exactly like you said!